# Doctrine does not insert when some attribute is null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm adding data to the database using entities and using the flush () and persist () Doctrine.
But when my entity has a null attribute, it does not insert into the database. The insert is made only when all attributes are filled.
How can I make it always enter data in the database?
This is my entity:

```
object(JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto)#74 (23) {
  ["id":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  NULL
  ["mora_dia":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  float(0)
  ["multa":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  float(0)
  ["detalhe":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  NULL
  ["ag_cod":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(15) "1893-7/536151-6"
  ["nossonumero":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(17) "15713790245291896"
  ["valor":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  float(10.8)
  ["sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(33) "XXXX"
  ["end_sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(21) "XXXXX"
  ["cep_sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(9) "09270-410"
  ["cidade_sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(11) "XXXXXX"
  ["cnpj_sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(18) "57.546.715.0001-61"
  ["inscricao_sacado":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(14) "XXXXX"
  ["notafiscal":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(7) "1872328"
  ["cod_cliente":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(10) "0000080537"
  ["linha":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(42) "01571.379021 45291.896178 2 62920001080249"
  ["vencimento_original":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#83 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-12-29 00:36:28"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  ["cedente":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(15) "BRF S.A.,BRASIL"
  ["cnpj_cedente":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(14) "01838723009850"
  ["carro":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(4) "0602"
  ["data_documento":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#38 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-11-18 00:36:28"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  ["num_documento":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  string(13) "001872328-001"
  ["data_proc":"JRP\Boleto\Entity\Boleto":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#67 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-11-19 00:36:28"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
```

}

Comment: add `nullable=true` to field definition in mapping file

Comment: would be nice to see your `enitity`.